# permutations in itertools cant print all permutations

Tags: python, python-itertools

My question is pretty straight forward:-

in python itertools why can I get a print of all permutations for say [,r =3]:

```
>>>import itertools
>>>print list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3], 3))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```

However only an empty list for [,r >3 e.g 10]:

```
>>>print list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3], 10))
[]
```

is there away of getting round this??

Comment: Because there is no permutation with 10 elements if you have only 3 elements to permute? What output did you expect? Did you mean all the combinations, or the product?

Comment: What output did you want?  Does `itertools.product([1, 2, 3], repeat=10)` do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [itertools docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) `permutations()` does not repeat elements.

I think you want `combinations_with_replacement()`

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

>>> print list(combinations_with_replacement([1, 2, 3], 10))

[(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)]
```